# What does it mean for $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What does it mean for $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2)$? What is the second derivative of $f$?

The first derivative, $Df$, is the 2 by 2 matrix of partial derivatives and $f \in C^1$ if the partial derivatives exist and are continuous. What is the similar statement for a map $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ to be twice differentiable?

Comment: it means that all entries of this matrix are differentiable

Comment: Can you give me a reference for the definition?

Comment: I don't currently have any book handy, but it should be in any introductory analysis book for math undergraduates.